# Unable to login to api connect through Node.js cli, though have access to API Connect portal

Tags: npm, ibm-cloud, apiconnect, apic

I am unable to login to APIConnect through command line, though i am able to successfully login to IBM API Connect portal (Signed-up on IBM Bluemix).

Below are the s/w versions i am using:

Windows 10,
Node js v6.12.3,
npm v3.10.10,
apic  v5.0.8.4-iFix (apiconnect: v2.8.39)

However, when i am trying to execute the below command, it is failing to login.

```
apic login -s apimanager.eu-gb.apiconnect.cloud.ibm.com -u <IBMid> -p <mypassword>
```

With this command, i am getting the below error:

> Error: Login to apimanager.eu-gb.apiconnect.cloud.ibm.com failed.
>   Please verify the server and credentials.

Can someone please let me know what needs to be done for cli login to api connect as i need this for continuous integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a detailed tutorial about logging into API Manager from apic CLI. It sets the server URL, orgs and catalog names.
[Publishing a project to IBM Cloud from the command line](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_cli_project_stage_command.html)

1. Run the apic config: `apic config:set catalog=apic-catalog://ibmcloud-base-url/orgs/org-name/catalogs/sb` .
2. Run `apic login --sso`  or `apic login --apiKey`

[image]

Comment: After setting up configuration and app property, I am still getting the same error once i provide the server name "apimanager.eu-gb.apiconnect.cloud.ibm.com". For me the catalog identifier is: 'apic config:set catalog=apic-catalog://apimanager.eu-gb.apiconnect.cloud.ibm.com/orgs/mnsayeed999gmailcom-dev/catalogs/sb'

Comment: Any help here pls?

Comment: Can you try following. Notice the change in server address:  `apic login -s eu.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com -u <IBMid> -p <mypassword>` or  `apic login -s us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com -u <IBMid> -p <mypassword>` . If it doesn't not work, try the api key route:  ` apic login -s eu.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com --apiKey`

Comment: Thank you so much...:) Now its working. The server name from the catalog definition is incorrect. 'apic login -s eu.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com -u <IBMid> -p <mypassword>' worked in my case.

Comment: just one last doubt, after closing the CLI, when i re-open it, and run the same command, the login fails. Does it require clearing cache or something of that sort?

Comment: try  `apic logout`